# GPG Keys getting deleted automatically

Tags: talend, gnupg

[image]I am using the following steps to import keys into GPG

1. Open prompt and fire import KEY command
2. Fire --edit-key KEY_NAME
3. Type trust and type 5 save
4. Place gpg.conf file at %APPDATA%/Roaming/gnupg and it only has one word ''batch'

I have two keys

1. PUBLIC KEY - Used for encrypting files
2. PUBLIC_PRiVATE KEY PAIR - Used for decrypting files. The public part we use for encrypting files for QA.

We have three talend jobs -  two of them use second key above for decrypting files and one uses first key for encrypting.
The jobs run at a frequency of 15 minutes.

The  problem I am facing is that the keys along with gpg.conf file get deleted almost after 24 hours and sometimes randomly. I could neither find public key nor key-pair, the gpg.conf also gets deleted.

I would be really grateful if someone can help me here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's not programming, sorry. you should ask at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks JimiDini I have created a question there also.

Comment: Can you show us an example of how your Talend jobs are interacting with your GPG key file? Is any other process touching the GPG key file?

Comment: We are using GPG for the first time hence, apart from the jobs no other process is using it.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use tSystem component with commons line argument supported by GPG provider. i have tried for huge file processing and it is working fine, even you can set temp path and get the decrypted file path using variables.